# Can we say "she has got"?

Tags: grammar

From a grammatical viewpoint, we can say the following sentence:

> I haven't got (= don't have) a car, but my sister has.

I want to know can we say the following rather than the above one?

> I haven't got (= don't have) a car, but my sister **has got**.

Comment: *Haven't got* is not the same thing as *don't have*. For example: *I* **don't have** *a car, but my sister* **does**.

Comment: I cannot understand your mean! In grammatical books have written haven't got = don't have. Actually, have got is common in the spoken. @Jason Bassford

Comment: *I do not have* and *I have not got* are not grammatically identical. If you have read any grammar books that say they are identical, they are very poor books indeed.

Comment: @Jason Bassfor I don't think "Essential Grammar in Use" is a poor book! http://s9.picofile.com/file/8346175050/2018_12_19_045104.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it's awkward.  The verb "to have got" usually takes an object, so it looks a little strange to just leave it hanging:

> I haven't got a car, but my sister has got **one**.

This is repetitive, so most native speakers would just say:

> I haven't got a car, but my sister **has** (one).